# yii2 how to get a string instead of a array with getRolesbyUser

Tags: arrays, yii2

**with:**
$userRole = yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($userId);

**got the array:**

```
$userRole = Array
(
    [author] => yii\rbac\Role Object
        (
            [type] => 1
            [name] => author
            [description] => 
            [ruleName] => 
            [data] => 
            [createdAt] => 1437713730
            [updatedAt] => 1437713730
        )

)
```

**want to just get a string:**

     the value of the **$userRole** is **'author'**.

---

**without using:** $userRole = array_keys(yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($userId))[0]

Comment: What if the user have more than one role ? it is about parsing the array or about figuring out how to get the role name directly instead of an array ?

Answer (score 1):

[getRolesByUser()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-managerinterface.html#getRolesByUser()-detail) was built to return all user's roles, we can't force it to expect him having only one role because that is not how **rbac** works, if you need to check if user can do a certain role, then use this instead :

```php
Yii::$app->user->can($role);
```

Otherwise if you really need  `$userRole` to hold the role name as a string value if the user have only one role, and lets say an array of roles if he got more, then this may be a cleaner way to do what you are asking for :

```php
$userRole = yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($userId);

// if no roles $userRole will be null by default
// so we better be sure that is not the case before doing the next

if ($userRole) {

    foreach ($userRole as $role) {
       $roles[] = $role->name;
    }

    // if user have 1 role then $userRole will be a string containing it
    // othewhise let $userRole be an array containing them all

    $userRole = count($roles) === 1 ? $roles[0] : $roles ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! That was what I want to know exactly: **yii2 don't have method to give the role back als string directly,** because one User may have more roles.

Comment: That's not how stackOverFlow works, you just added a new answer to the question, you do such a thing when your are providing a different solution to the problem.